# React map object as array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I know its possible to map an array of some sort like so:

```
{sumArray.map((summary, index) => (
    <Col className="stat-element" key={index}>
        
    </Col>
))}
```

However I want to map a single object by each of its properties:

```
const [summary, setSummary] = useState([{rank: 0}, {trending: 0}, {totalTaskCompleted: 0}, {avgTaskCorrect: 0}, {avgTaskTime: 0 }]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (parentToChild){
            console.log(parentToChild)
            const result = Object.values(parentToChild);
            setSummary(result);
            console.log(result);
        }

      }, [])
```

However on output this strips the properties title, how do I make it retain the properties name so I can display each within the following? :

```
{summary.map((property, index) => (
    <Col className="stat-element" key={index}>
        {index} {propertyname} {property}
    </Col>
))}
```

Comment: The `summary` state is an array of objects, each object with a different single key/property. What are you trying to do? Map the `summary` to output like `<Col>0 rank 0</Col><Col>1 trending 0</Col> ...`?

Comment: Maybe have a look at [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries). It returns an array of key/value pairs.

Comment: `summary` is an Array and each element in the array is an object (which has `rank`, `trending`, etc as props). So, you need to first iterate over the`summary` array and for each element, you need to iterate over its props. Try something like so: `{sumArray.map((summary, arrIdx) => Object.entries(summary).map(([propName, propVal]), propIdx) => (<Col className..> {arrIdx} {propIdx} {propName} {propVal} </Col>)))}`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should then declare summary as an object and not an array and then you could use the Object.keys methods:

```
const [summary, setSummary] = useState({rank: 0, trending: 0, totalTaskCompleted: 0, avgTaskCorrect: 0, avgTaskTime: 0 });

(...)

Object.keys(summary).map((key, index) => (
    <Col className="stat-element" key={index}>
        {index} {key} {summary[key]}
    </Col>
))}
```

Comment: `summary` is an array, so the keys are the array indices, each `summary[key]` an object.

Comment: gotcha the question didn't fit the example :)  updated